# Flex, how to process HTML file

Tags: html, c, libcurl, flex-lexer

I am using libcurl and flex to download images from an webpage.

I already have the libcurl easy functions set to download any HTML file from a given url and I also have the regular expression but now I don't know how to process the downloaded HTML file.

example:
I have the file "fp" downloaded and saved in a specific location and now I need to pass the fp to the regular expressions to process but the structure of my file is:

```
    %{ 
#include <...>
...
%}

%% 
/* Regular expressions */

%%
int main () {
... //c code with file fp downloaded and saved
}
```

So, how do I "send" the fp file to the regular expression to process ?

Any suggestions ?
Thanks.

Comment: `extern FILE * yyin; yyin = fp` should do it

Comment: And if I do that after saving the file I can call the yylex() after ? And how do I do to process the yyin file with my regular expression ? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the comment from the ***user58697*** I start reading about *yyin* and discovered that after having a file opened in C you can delegate it to the yyin by doing:

`fp = yyin`

Assuming that your file is called fp.

Once you do that, the file will be processed in the regular expressions.

I found my solution in the 2nd example of
[this page](http://aquamentus.com/tut_lexyacc.html).

Comment: The oposite! `yyin = fp`